# Using an utilities library (headers-only) in multiple modules with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have this kind of arborescence:

```
Project    
 CMakeList.txt
 -- Module 1
    CMakeList.txt
    -- include
    -- src
       CMakeList.txt
 -- Module 2    
 -- ...
 -- utilities (Headers Only - It will have .cpp probably later)
   -- include
      -- typedefs.h
      -- ..
```

I would like to be able to use my Utilities library into any modules.
I've tried using

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries

My Utilities cmakelist.txt

```
project(Utilities LANGUAGES CXX)
```

When I try to include into my cpp files

```
#include "utilities/include/typedefs.h"
```

It cannot find the file. I've tried with : (doesn't work)

```
#include "include/typedefs.h"
#include "typedefs.h"
```

I'm trying to find what do I need to do into my module CMakeList.txt files so that the compiler can find the #include statement.

The top level has :

```
...
add_subdirectory(utilities)
add_subdirectory(Module1)
add_subdirectory(Module2)
..
```

I added into the top-level cmakelist.txt : (doesn't work)

```
include_directories("${Utilities_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

I do not have to link it yet, since there is not .cpp file. I just need to be able to #include into the different modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html) along with your target.
As an example:

```
target_include_directories(my_target PUBLIC "${Utilities_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

Then, all the source files that belong to the target `my_target` will be able to access to the headers as:

```
#include <typedefs.h>
```

Use relative paths otherwise.

Comment: With the `#include <typedefs.h>` it doesn't find the file and neither with the other kind of path with `#include "...", But it's really weird, It works with CLion, but doesn't work with QtCreator...

Comment: @Lorac I use QtCreator. It has problems following the inclusions made with cmake, but if you launch the build it usually works.